# Enumerating elements of a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a table and I want to enumerate each element.

Something like this

```
@foreach($elements as $element)
<tr>
<td>{{ (isset($a))?$a++:($a = 1) }}</td>
<td>...
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I expect the table to begin with 1 and then count on, however, the first two columns are always 1. I have already solved this problem by giving the template an `$a = 0;` on the controller but I want to know why my first solution doesn't work and if there is a workaround

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Jerodev I am using 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Blade has a very handy variable for loops, called [the $loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable). This lets you gather information about the current element of the list, including the index and iteration count.

So you can do just this:

```
@foreach($elements as $element)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>...
    </tr>
@endforeach
```